# Pattern Unlock Screen (new activity, not using the system one)

Tags: android, locking, design-patterns

I'm trying to make a screen with a pattern like Android Pattern Screen but not using it (I don't want lock my phone, only put a "private" section with a "door").

I need a screen to control the access a special section of my app so I have thought to use a pattern screen.

How can I do this? Where can I found a piece of code or and example?

Thanks :)

PD. The Screen I need is similar to this: http://www.actualidadgoogle.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/11/patron-desbloq-android.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the code from the android source. You can find the source [here](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android-apps/2.3_r1/com/android/settings/ChooseLockPattern.java/)